# ¿Cómo creo un array PHP para mostrar los resultados que devuelve Api?

Tags: php, array, api

¡Hola a todos!

Soy nuevo en el mundo de las Api y sé leer código PHP y replicarlo.

Tengo un código que me devuelve los resultados de una Api pero quiero darle formato; para ello quiero obtener los últimos 10 resultados de la consulta.

El código php es el siguiente:

```
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.formula1.com/v1/video-assets/videos",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "apikey: XxxXXxXxxxXxXxXxxxxx",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 156c003c-0b34-f357-96b3-bb92363b2b38"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$datos = json_decode($response,true);
$videoIdreciente = $datos ["videos"][0]["videoId"];
$tituloreciente = $datos ["videos"][0]["caption"];
$descreciente = $datos ["videos"][0]["description"];
$imagenreciente = $datos ["videos"][0]["thumbnail"]["path"];
$urlreciente = $datos ["videos"][0]["url"];

$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo "<h1>".$tituloreciente."</h1><br>";
    echo "<h4>".$descreciente."</h4><br>";
    echo "<h4>".$urlreciente."</h4><br>";
    echo "<video-js id='myPlayerID' data-video-id='".$videoIdreciente."' data-account='00000000000' data-player='XXXXXXxxx' data-embed='default' data-application-id class='video-js' controls width='640' height='360'></video-js>";
    
}
```

Si yo lo hago agregando las respuestas `[0][1][2]...` sé que va a funcionar pero no es la forma ideal.

¿Puede indicarme alguien cuál es el array y orden correcto?

Comment: Los resultados los mostraré con el listado de imágenes de las 10 consultas y con un popup que abra el respectivo vídeo

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento  de este sitio, y de paso consigas tu primera medalla! Tambien te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que aprendas a realizar las preguntas de forma que todos podamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo tienes que poner en un bucle `for` de este modo:

```php
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $salida = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $salida .= '
          <h1>'.$datos["videos"][$i]["videoId"].'</h1>
          <h4>'.$datos["videos"][$i]["description"].'</h4>
          <h4>'.$datos["videos"][$i]["url"].'</h4>
          <video-js id="myPlayerID" data-video-id="'.$datos["videos"][$i]["videoId"].'" data-account="00000000000" data-player="XXXXXXxxx" data-embed="default" data-application-id class="video-js" controls width="640" height="360"></video-js>
        ';
    };
    echo $salida;
};
```

**Explicación:**
Fíjate que al ponerlo dentro de un bucle `for` podemos modificar el [0] por el siguiente número en cada iteración de forma más cómoda de como ya sabias hacerlo tu, gracias a la variable `$i`, e ir concatenando la $salida hasta el `echo` final fuera del bucle.